# SQL show based on date condition

Tags: sql

I have following query to start of with:

```
Select *
from AAF21OKN$                  
where Service like '%AAF21%'
  OR Ydelse like '%UXM%'
  OR Ydelse like '%UXU%'
  OR Ydelse like '%UXR%'
  OR Ydelse like '%UXZ%'
Order by [Patient ID], [Date]
```

I then get following table (only a snapshot for better desciption):

```
Patient ID    Date                      Service
----------    -----------------------   ------            
Forløb08196   2020-03-04 00:00:00.000   UXMG25
Forløb08196   2020-03-06 00:00:00.000   AAF21 OKN
Forløb08196   2020-03-06 00:00:00.000   UXRG25BES

Forløb10030   2020-02-03 00:00:00.000   AAF21 OKN
Forløb10030   2020-02-04 00:00:00.000   UXMG25
```

I now have a problem:

- I only want to show the services where the service starting with 'AAF21 OKN' is first (by date).
- Patient ID: 'Forløb10030' is for example what i want.
- But in Patient ID: 'Forløb08196', I don't want the Service 'UXMG25' row to be showed. As it has happened before the service 'AAF21 OKN'

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're after, I think the following will meet your needs:

```
--Part 1
SELECT *
FROM AAF21OKN$ t1
WHERE
t1.Service Like '%AAF21%'
--Part 2
OR (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM AAF21OKN$ t2
            WHERE t2.Service like '%AAF21%'
            AND t2.[Patient ID] = t1.[Patient ID]
            AND t2.Date <= t1.Date)
    AND (
          t2.Ydelse like '%UXM%'
          OR t2.Ydelse like '%UXU%'
          OR t2.Ydelse like '%UXR%'
          OR t2.Ydelse like '%UXZ%'
        )
    )
```

The *Part 1* gets you all the "AAF21 OKN" records. *Part 2* gets you all the other records, but only where there `EXISTS` an "AAF21 OKN" record for the same patient which is on the same date or earlier (you may want to change the `<=` to `<` depending on your expectations).

Comment: Great. Glad I could help. If you could mark my answer as accepted that would be great. Not sure if you can also upvote as a new user. I think what confused the others who responded was your comment that you "only want" cases where one of the record types was first, which they understandably took to mean that in cases where it wasn't first, you weren't interested in the patient at all, when actually you only wanted the details from that point onward. Asking questions as clearly as possible goes a long way here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

In Standard SQL, you can use `first_value()`:

```
select a.*
from (Select a.*,
             first_value(service) over (partition by [Patient ID] order by date) as first_service
      from AAF21OKN$ a      
      where Service like '%AAF21%' or
           Ydelse like '%UXM%' or
           Ydelse like '%UXU%' or
           Ydelse like '%UXR%' or
           Ydelse like '%UXZ%'
     ) a
where first_service = 'AAF21 OKN'
Order by [Patient ID], [Date];
```

If you only wanted the patient, then you can use aggregation.  Or `not exists`:

```
select a.*
from AAF21OKN$ a 
where a.service = 'AAF21 OKN' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from AAF21OKN$ a2
                  where a2.[Patient ID] = a.[Patient ID] and
                        (Ydelse like '%UXM%' or
                         Ydelse like '%UXU%' or
                         Ydelse like '%UXR%' or
                         Ydelse like '%UXZ%'
                        ) and
                        a2.date < a.date
                 );
```

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff. The first suggestion is very close to what I want. But as Patient ID: 'Forløb08196', don't start with 'AAF21 OKN', it dosn't show it in the output now. I still want to see 'Forløb08196' but just not the first row containing service 'UXMG25'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `min` analytical function as follows:

```
select * from
(select t.*,
       min(case when service = 'AAF21 OKN' then date end) over (partition by Patient_id) as min_dt
  from your_table t
 where Service like '%AAF21%'
    OR Ydelse like '%UXM%'
    OR Ydelse like '%UXU%'
    OR Ydelse like '%UXR%'
    OR Ydelse like '%UXZ%') t
where date >= min_dt
```

Comment: Thanks @Popeye, When I'm trying to use your function I got a lot of extra services. I therefore tried to modify it to only get wanted services

` SELECT * FROM (SELECT t.*, min(case WHEN [Service] = 'AAF21 OKN' THEN [Date] END) OVER (partition by [Patient ID]) AS min_dt FROM AAF21OKN$ t) t WHERE [Date] >= min_dt And Service LIKE '%AAF21%' OR Service LIKE '%UXM%' OR Service LIKE '%UXU%' OR Service LIKE '%UXR%' OR Service LIKE '%UXZ%' Order by [Patient ID], [Date];`

But then the OUTPUT looks like when i first started out

Comment: No, You are using the WHERE clause outside the sub-query. Use it as I have used it in my answer. It is inside the sub-query